# Are threads more efficient in a multi-core environment?

Tags: java, c, multithreading, programming-languages

I'm referring to the Threads usage.
While I was studying the importance of threads, an ambiguity arose in my mind:

Are threads give more efficient on single core or multi core computers?

Comment: They perform better on multi-core, but remember when you are working with threads, lot of what-if conditions arise.

Comment: I think it is agnostic of single/multi core. The advantage of using threads is apparent in whichever processor that supports scheduling. The underlying principle is that context switching between threads is much cheaper that context switching between processes.

Comment: Multicore will be more efficient only in case you have lots of thread to utilize more than on core. Read this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076147/java-web-development/java-threads-may-not-use-all-your-cpus.html) for some info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can benefit on both, depending on how you use them.

On single core, if you have two background tasks which perform some calculations independently from each other, then it may not be wise to assign each of them to a separate thread. This is because what you get is pure context switching overhead, without any performance improvement.
On the other hand, if you have a UI thread and a background working thread, your program can be more interactive(e.g. the user can do something else) since the UI thread is not blocked by the CPU intensive tasks.

On multi-core system, one difference is that each core can run a thread physically. So you can have multiple threads running in parallel. That benefit is true regardless of those threads are all background working threads, or one UI thread, one working thread, etc.

Comment: Thanks that's what I want to know !